# Installing additional driver for Networked Printer

Tags: printer, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm pretty new to the whole server thing and am using some VM's at home to mess around. Essentially I have installed a printer which is connected into my router and has a static IP. I've installed the printer on my 2008 R2 (64bit) VM and created a script to install the printer for my XP and Windows 7 Client VM's (32bit) - but they can't install because there is no driver!

So I understand I need to use the Additional drivers option under the Sharing tab on the Printer.

Do I add the 2008 R2 32bit driver?
Do I add the Windows 7 32bit driver?

Since I have XP and 7 I don't know which x86 driver to add?

Comment: To clarify it a bit. You want to add the driver for the OS that is going to use it. Since your client are "Windows 7 32bit VM" you want the driver for that. For an XP client you want the XP driver. Many printer drivers come in big 'generic' version which only rougly have to match, which is why john's answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule it just needs to be a 32 bit driver, and won't matter which OS it is for. In fact you might find it difficult to find a driver that distinguishes OS version.

I have come across this issue recently and the installation can be a little complicated:

As the server is 64-bit you may struggle to get the driver installed using the print management tools on the server.

In the past what I have had to do is open print management on a 32-bit client and then connect to the server from there. You are then remotely managing the print server.

You can now install the driver for the printer using an 32-bit driver and I don't think it matters as long as the platform is correct and (quite important) the driver has the same name as the 64-bit version.

Comment: The answer is much appreciated!!! Many thanks John

Comment: Please could you accept it if you agree to it being the solution to your issue.